# Automatically resolving Git merge conflicts in a particular folder containing autogenerated code

Tags: git

When resolving merge conflicts in Git, is it possible to set up your local Git repository to automatically take the right-hand side for only particular folders?

The reason I'm asking is because I am working on a codebase which has a large portion of autogenerated code. Whenever I am resolving merge conflicts during a rebase, I **never** attempt to hand-merge conflicting code in the folder containing the autogenerated code. I simply skip over those files, and after I'm done with the rebase, I regenerate the code using our tools. I just don't trust myself to correctly hand-merge code that has been generated by a tool. It's just too risky!

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Note : classically, that's one of the reasons *not* to track generated files or build objects, only source code. Most projects put these files in `.gitignore`

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: consider a "theirs" merge driver, such as [this one](https://gist.github.com/dpwright/2657356) (it's not mine, it's quite trivial, and in fact you don't need a shell script at all, at least on Unix-like systems).  Be aware of its limitations.  You would set this up with a `.gitattributes` file and your Git configuration file (personal `--global` config, or one in the repository).  Note that while the `.gitattributes` file is included in all clones, the configuration is not, so everyone who wants to use this has to configure the driver command.

#### Long

You *can* set up a *merge driver* that takes "their" copy of the file, but there is a danger here: your merge driver is *only* invoked in the case of a conflict.  You would need to have this driver work on all files within the desired part of the repository, since Git only stores files (no folders, just files with names that contain slashes).

Remember that merge's job is to *combine changes*.  When `git merge` runs, it finds three commits.  The middle one is very easy because it's the *current* commit, and the last one is very easy because you name it with your `git merge` command.  It's the first one that is tricky: the first commit that `git merge` needs is the *merge base*.

Git finds the merge base on its own, using the *commit graph*.  Some viewing tools show you this commit graph automatically (e.g., `gitk` and some of the fancier GUIs); or `git log --graph`, which you might combine with `--oneline`, draws a crude but useful ASCII graph.

Since each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file, merge works by:

- compare the merge base snapshot to our snapshot: `git diff --find-renames hash-of-base HEAD`
- compare the merge base snapshot to their snapshot: `git diff --find-renames hash-of-base other`

For each file that's in all three commits, this comparison says "we changed the file" (by doing whatever) and/or "they changed the file" (by doing whatever), or "nobody changed the file at all".

(For files that are only in one or two commits, the situation is obviously somewhat different, but the same idea holds: we changed, they changed, or both.)

If only *one side* of the merge *changed* a file, Git takes that side's copy of the file.  You don't get a choice here: your own merge driver, the one you define to handle conflicts, never runs at all.  If that's OK, great!  If not, well, you don't get a choice.

If *both sides* of the merge *changed* a file, Git will use its own built-in merge driver by default, but if you tell Git, via `.gitattributes`, that you have your own merge driver, Git will run *your* command, whatever that is, rather than using its built-in default.

[The gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) has a remarkably clear (by Git documentation standards) description of how to set up a merge driver.  The actual driver you need is quite trivial:

```
[merge "theirs"]
    name = use-theirs merge driver
    driver = cp %B %A
```

Your `.gitattributes` file would then contain the line:

```
path/to/folder/in/question/*  merge=theirs
```

Note that you could just create a file named `.gitattributes` under this path (`path/to/folder/in/question`) that says `* merge=theirs`, but if you do so, any conflicting changes to this file will be merged by the `theirs` merge driver.  This is probably not what you want.